# Xamarin Android: HttpRequestException: No route to host

Tags: android, xamarin.android

My application was previously running fine but from few days, without any change I am getting exception

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No route to host
```

The complete exception is as follows.

> {System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No route to host ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No route to host
>     at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync (System.String host, System.Int32 port, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00110] in <99e6bf942304234315ba19eac23497e256>:0 
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>     at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync (System.String host, System.Int32 port, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x001ac] in <99e6bf9d99234215ba19eacc7497e256>:0 
>     at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1[TResult].get_Result () [0x0001b] in <6de489942345dbea42342d8c6>:0 
>     at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00134] in <99e6bf9d99304315ba19eacc7497e256>:0 
>     at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1[TResult].get_Result () [0x0001b] in <6de48997d0c0445dbea8d4d83492d8c6>:0 
>     at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync (System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1[TResult] creationTask) [0x000a2] in <99e6bf9d9342043152342eacc7497e256>:0 
>     at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1[TResult].get_Result () [0x0001b] in <6de48997d4234bea8d4d234d8c6>:0 
>     at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Boolean doRequestAuth, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00089] in <99e6bf9d993234a19eacc7497e256>:0 
>     at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000ba] in <99e6bf9d234304315ba19eac2345256>:0 
>     at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] sendTask, System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource cts, System.Boolean disposeCts) [0x000b3] in <99e6bf9d99304315ba19eacc7497e256>:0 
>     at Refit.RequestBuilderImplementation+<>c__DisplayClass11_0`1[T].b__0 (System.Net.Http.HttpClient client, System.Threading.CancellationToken ct, System.Object[] paramList) [0x00115] in <573dbb234a499ea234c22312349ab6>:0 
>     at MyApp.Droid.Activities.ActivityLogin.GetToken () [0x000c2] in /ActivityLogin.cs:624 }

My url is something like https://someservice.com:8080
I also have added android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in android menifest file.
Please guide me in this regard.

Comment: Is your server working perfect?

Comment: yes, I get the response on postman. It is working fine.

Comment: My app was working fine but few days back, it get crashed. when i debugged through the code I got the above exception.

Comment: What do you want to do with code? Use the app to connect to the url? If yes, how do you connect?

Comment: Are you using localhost or is it a public webpage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested all the above scenarios but nothing did any trick. I was testing the app in my office. When I tested the same app at my home, It worked perfectly. The issue was due to restrictions on office network. . . ports were also not allowed, so this issue happened. Now restrictions are removed for my devices so app is working fine in office too.

Answer (score 0):

Just try bellow solution maybe work for you if it is related to SSL

Create one file in `xml` directory with `network_security_configx.xml` name  and bellow code
**res -> xml -> network_security_configx.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

And then add below code in your `AndroidManifest` `<application>`

```
<application
        android:name=".volley.AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"
       >
.....
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a DNS problem, try to use a Base URL with the direct address of the server that the APIs is hosted and not use a Domain/Subdomain to test if works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this happens very often for Mobile Apps when using APIs, so for solution this kind of problems I use the library Polly for resilience, works very fine with the Xamarin using the Policy WaitAndRetryAsync:

```
await Policy
        .Handle<Exception>()
        .WaitAndRetryAsync
        (
            retryCount: 3,
            sleepDurationProvider: retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt)),
            onRetry: (ex, time) =>
            {
                IsError = true;//bool that show the text with the message
                cont++;
                Mensage = $"Error on load data: {ex.Message}, trying again ({cont})..";
                Crashes.TrackError(ex);//using the library of app center to register the exception
            }
        )
        .ExecuteAsync(async () =>
        {
            //your code to call the API;                              
        });
```